# Remove object by inherited object id in Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, filter

This is my parent array, I need to remove the whole object when there is an id match the `selectedData` -> `personId`

```
 const [parentArr, setParentArr] = React.useState([
    {
      date: " Mon Aug 08 2022",
      selectedData: { personId: 2233, personName: "mary" }
    },
    {
      date: " Mon Aug 08 2022 ",
      selectedData: { personId: 2223, personName: "jane" }
    }
  ]);
```

This is the function I use to remove an item but it returns `selectedData object`

```
  const removeItem = () => {
        const hardcodeId = 2223;
        // for this is use hardcoded id here
        const selectedDataCopy = [...parentArr];
        const getSelectedDataArrays = selectedDataCopy?.map(
          (item, i) => item.selectedData
        );
        const getSelectedDataArraysRemove = getSelectedDataArrays?.filter(
          (item, i) => item.personId !== hardcodeId
        );
        setParentArr(getSelectedDataArraysRemove)
      };
```

I expect an array like this after removeItem triggered

```
  const [parentArr, setParentArr] = React.useState([
    {
      date: " Mon Aug 08 2022",
      selectedData: [{ personId: 2233, personName: "mary" }]
    }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

item.selectedData you should write

you don't need to return with map just write this

```
const getSelectedDataArraysRemove = data?.filter(
      (item, i) => item.selectedData.personId !== 2223
    );
```